# (Large) div horizontally centered inside smaller div. Pure CSS solution possible?

Tags: css, html, css-position, centering

**I would like to have the "Shadow" div centered horizontally inside "Wrapper".** Since the specific width of the "Wrapper" is unknown due to width: 100%, it is also unknown whether the "Shadow" div is larger or smaller than its container.

Is this even possible? I could not think of any solution. Auto margin doesnt work. **CSS&HTML only please**.

Code for demonstration:

HTML:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="Shadow">some content</div>
  <div class="Content">some content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Wrapper{ width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; background: url(path) top center no-repeat; max-width: 1520px; max-height: 1050px; overflow: hidden; }
.Shadow{ width: 1520px; height: 1050px; }
.Content{ position:absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 800px; height: 500px; }
```

Comment: try margin:auto; add this tag to shadow class,

Comment: As stated before, this doesnt work.

Comment: removed my answer. since Martin Turjak his answer looks more viable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kggD2/)**

where you use `margin-left: 50%` to move the child to the center of the wrapper and then using `left` to move the child left for half of its width.

relevant lines of CSS from my example:

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    /* other properties */
}
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    left: -200px;
    /* other properties */
}
```

#### Or alternatively:

you coul use `transform:translate(-760px);` in place of `left` - then you don't need to position the shadow element absolutely, see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kggD2/1/).

Comment: Thanks! Althought not specified in original, is this possible for vertical centering? Seems to behave differently for vertical centering.

Comment: Was talking about original solution

Comment: @martin Or, if only support for modern browser is concerned, one can even use `transform:translateX(-50%);` :D

Comment: vertical align is usually a bit more tricky ... but there are always options **http://jsfiddle.net/kggD2/2/**